# what is the right List cast to retrieve data from hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I am trying to retrieve data from hibernate. I inserted following data in the `Users` table in the Database.

```
userId=2
userName=kiko
password=kareem
```

Now I want to retrieve them again but I don't know the right cast for `List<>` , because when i tried to retrieve from `users1` object, it is now found by the code :

```
out.println(users1.getUserName());
```

---

Here's my code

**login.java (servlet)**

```java
    package Controller;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    import HibernateClasses.Users;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class login
     */
    @WebServlet("/login")
    public class login extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public login() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
         *      response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
         *      response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String name = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            out.println("your name is " + name);

            // Users users = new Users();

            SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Users.IdPass");
            query.setString(0, name);
            query.setString(1, password);
             List<Users> users1 = query.list();
            Users users = (Users) query.list();


            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();

            System.out.println(users.getUserName());

        }

    }
```

**login.jsp**

```jsp
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="login" method="POST">
                <ul>
                    <li>User <input type="text" name="username"><br></li>
                    <li>Password <input type="password" name="password"></li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Users.java**

```java
    package HibernateClasses;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;

    @Entity
    @NamedNativeQueries({
            @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Users.byId", query = "Select * from users where userId=?", resultClass = Users.class),
            @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Users.all", query = "Select * from users ", resultClass = Users.class),
            @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Users.IdPass", query = "Select * from users where userName=? and password=? ", resultClass = Users.class) })
    public class Users {
        @Id
        private int userId;
        private String userName;
        private String password;

        public int getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(int userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

    }
```

**console**

```
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Archive System' did not find a matching property.
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 7 2015 13:07:11 UTC
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.67.0
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\kiko\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\kiko\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\kiko\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;.
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 637 ms
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 920 ms
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Feb 11, 2016 12:48:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Controller.login] in context with path [/Archive_System] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityListeners
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.getDefaults(JPAMetadataProvider.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getDefaults(JavaReflectionManager.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
    at Controller.login.doPost(login.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show us the jar files included in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityListeners
```

indicate that you miss some jar file to include in your class path or project.

You may add dependency jar file using below Maven code :

```
<!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: should i move my all JARs(hibernate+databse,...etc) in WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: yes.. and also check that it is include in your deployment folder or on class path.

Comment: i don't use Maven , now i have copy all jars in lib folder and they still in the user library but it the console changed its read the select statement , can you tell me about the right List cast to retrieve data

Answer (score 0):

You should change this code

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
            @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Users.byId", query = "Select * from users where userId=?", resultClass = Users.class),
            @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Users.all", query = "Select * from users ", resultClass = Users.class),
            @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Users.IdPass", query = "Select * from users where userName=? and password=? ", resultClass = Users.class) })
```

to

```
 @NamedQueries({
            @NamedQuery(name = "Users.byId", query = "from Users u where u.userId=?"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Users.all", query = "from Users"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Users.IdPass", query = "from Users u where u.userName=? and u.password=? ") })
```

See example of using `@NamedQuery` annotation [Hibernate Named Query](http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-named-query)

> The Hibernate named query is way to use any query by some meaningful
>   name. It is like using alias names. The Hibernate framework provides
>   the concept of named queries so that application programmer need not
>   to scatter queries to all the java code.
>
> There are two ways to define the named query in hibernate:
>
> - by annotation
> - by mapping file.
>
> #### Hibernate Named Query by annotation
>
> If you want to use named query in Hibernate, you need to have
>   knowledge of `@NamedQueries` and `@NamedQuery` annotations.
>
> `@NameQueries` annotation is used to define the multiple named queries.
>
> `@NameQuery` annotation is used to define the single named query.
>
> Let's see the example of using the named queries:
>
> ```
> @NamedQueries({  
>    @NamedQuery(  
>      name = "findEmployeeByName",  
>      query = "from Employee e where e.name = :name"  
>    )  
> })
> ```

About list cast: the  `list()` returns objects like it's used in the `from` clause. For example in above query it returns `List<Employee>` that doesn't require additional casts.